# how do i mute someone and not even allow him to press any buttons with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a bot which sends a button on ready when users press the button an embed with a  captcha image is shown with a button linking to a modal if the modal response doesnt match the captcha he /she should be muted for 2hours and cant press any buttons for 2hrs

I tried every thing but didnt find a relevant solution

Comment: You can't make a button and prevent a user from clicking it. What you _can_ do is check if they're muted in the `callback`, and if so show them a message of some sorts instead of running your regular code. A basic `if-statement` should do the trick on that.